# Create name-value pair data frame from input with delimiters

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a data frame which can be created with this code:

```
input <- data.frame( 'ID'=c(1:3), 
                      Destination=c("A\r\nB", "C", "D\r\nE\r\nF"), 
                      Topic=c("W", "X", "Y\r\nZ") )
```

It looks like this:

```
  ID Destination  Topic
1  1      A\r\nB      W
2  2           C      X
3  3 D\r\nE\r\nF Y\r\nZ
```

I would like to create an output data frame that looks like this:

```
desiredOutput <- data.frame( 
   ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3) , 
   name=c( "Destination", "Destination", "Topic", "Destination", "Topic",
           "Destination", "Destination", "Destination" , "Topic", "Topic"), 
   value=c("A","B", "W", "C", "X", "D", "E", "F", "Y", "Z") )

   ID        name value
1   1 Destination     A
2   1 Destination     B
3   1       Topic     W
4   2 Destination     C
5   2       Topic     X
6   3 Destination     D
7   3 Destination     E
8   3 Destination     F
9   3       Topic     Y
10  3       Topic     Z
```

Whenever the delimiter `\r\n` occurs, I would like to split the contents into separate rows, with the correct ID, the name of the column, and the corresponding value.

I can split a single column into a list using `strsplit`, but I don't know how to put the contents into a data frame as above apart from attempting to write a loop. I expect the `tidyr` package might be helpful.

```
strsplit(input$Destination, split = "\r\n")
```

How can this be done, ideally without a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With tidyr, `gather` to long form, then use `separate_rows` to separate the joined elements:

```
library(tidyr)

input %>% gather(name, value, -ID) %>% separate_rows(value)
##    ID        name value
## 1   1 Destination     A
## 2   1 Destination     B
## 3   2 Destination     C
## 4   3 Destination     D
## 5   3 Destination     E
## 6   3 Destination     F
## 7   1       Topic     W
## 8   2       Topic     X
## 9   3       Topic     Y
## 10  3       Topic     Z
```

**Note:** If your data is factors instead of character, `tidyr` will warn you, as it coerces to character in order to rearrange. It will work regardless, but if you hate warnings, coerce to character manually before reshaping.

Comment: Nice. I was thinking the same with data.table as in `library(data.table) ; melt(setDT(input), 1, value.factor = FALSE)[, unlist(strsplit(value, "\r\n")), by = variable]` but I like your syntax better here

Comment: This is very elegant, but gives me some extra rows where data should not be split. I have an example that looks like `A_B\r\nC_D`. It should not be split by the `_`, only by `\r\n`

Comment: Ah, `separate` assumes non-alphanumeric characters are separators. To restrict, just specify: `separate_rows(value, sep = '\r\n')`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(input), id.var = "ID", variable.name = "name")[,
      .(value = unlist(strsplit(value, "\\s+"))), .(ID, name)][order(ID)]
#     ID        name value
#1:  1 Destination     A
#2:  1 Destination     B
#3:  1       Topic     W
#4:  2 Destination     C
#5:  2       Topic     X
#6:  3 Destination     D
#7:  3 Destination     E
#8:  3 Destination     F
#9:  3       Topic     Y
#10: 3       Topic     Z
```

EDIT: A similar solution was commented by @DavidArenburg in another solution (which I didn't see earlier).